# These words have same properties

Tags: word, wordplay

what do these words have in common?

> devil, denim, relive, diaper, lager, deliver, lever, drawer, sleep,
>   stink, loops, loots, parts, stressed, timer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All these words...

> Can be reversed to get another meaningful word.

As in:

> devil -> LIVED
>  denim -> MINED
>  relive -> EVILER ([hmmm](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/eviler))
>  diaper -> REPAID
>  lager -> REGAL
>  deliver -> REVILED
>  lever -> REVEL
>  drawer -> REWARD
>  sleep -> PEELS
>  stink -> KNITS
>  loops -> SPOOL
>  loots -> STOOL
>  parts -> STRAP
>  stressed -> DESSERTS
>  timer -> REMIT

Answer (score 8):

> *Take your best* mug
>  *and fill it with* decaf
>  *Sharpen up with a* strop
>  *And don't fall into the* trap
>  *Of stirring it with silver* spoons
>
>  *This answer may not be the* top
>  *But I'll tell you how it's* made
>  *Take each word and* swap
>  *The direction that it's* laid
>  *Then you see from front to back it* spins

Comment: Haha you add more examples in your answer. Creative poem. +1